# jQuery .click() doesn't fire but console.log shows output

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having a problem in my code where I click a DOM-element using JavaScript. The click does not work and I am almost sure it is no dumb programming mistake (always dangerous to say).

After deleting some DOM-elements I want my code to click an element and trigger its onclick event. However this doesn't work. According to my code the event triggers but the event doesn't happen and the click event returns the jQuery object.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="castor-tabs">
  <div class="castor-tab" data-path="../SiteBuilding/alertbox.js" data-saved="saved" data-editor="5475c897f1900editor">
    <span class="castor-filename">alertbox.js</span>
    <span class="castor-close"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-times"></i></span>
  </div>
  <div class="castor-tab" data-path="../SiteBuilding/index.php" data-saved="saved" data-editor="5475c89903e70editor">
    <span class="castor-filename">index.php</span>
    <span class="castor-close"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-times"></i></span>
  </div>
  <div class="castor-tab active" data-path="../SiteBuilding/makesite.php" data-saved="saved" data-editor="5475c8997ac77editor">
    <span class="castor-filename">makesite.php</span>
    <span class="castor-close"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-times"></i></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$(".castor-tabs").on("click", ".castor-close", function() {
    var tab = $(this).parent();
    if(tab.attr("data-saved") == "saved") {
        // File is saved

        if($(".castor-tab").length > 1) {
            // 1 element is 'tab' the other is a second tab
            if(tab.next().length > 0) {
                // If element is to the right
                window.newTab = tab.next();
            } else if(tab.prev().length > 0) {
                // If element is to the left
                window.newTab = tab.prev();
            }
        } else {
            window.newTab = false;
        }

        var editor = tab.attr("data-editor");
        $("#" + editor).remove(); // textarea linked to CodeMirror
        $("#" + editor + "editor").remove(); // Huge CodeMirror-element
        tab.remove();

        if(window.newTab) {
            console.log("window.newTab.click()");
            console.log(window.newTab.click()); // Simulate click()
        }
    } else {
        // File isn't saved
    }
});
```

The onclick event:

```
$(".castor-tabs").on("click", ".castor-tab", function() {
    $(".castor-tab.active").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
    var editor = $(this).attr("data-editor");
    $(".CodeMirror").hide();
    $("#" + editor).show();
});
```

I saved the element in the window object for a reason. After the code runs and it skips the click-part I still have the DOM-element i want to click saved in the window object. This means I can run

```
console.log(window.newTab.click());
```

again. Surprisingly this **does** click the element and this **does** activate the click-event. It also returns the DOM-element instead of the jQuery-object.

[image]

The image shows in the first two lines the failed click. The third line is my manual input and the fourth line is the successful return value of the click().

I hope you can help me to solve this.

**UPDATE**

.trigger("click") unfortunately gives the same output..

[image]

**UPDATE 2**

To help you i made the website available on a subdomain. I know many of you hate it if you have to go to a different page but I hope you'll forgive me because in my opinion this cant be solved through JSFiddle.

The link is http://castor.marknijboer.nl.

After clicking some pages to open try closing them and you'll see what i mean.

Comment: a Jsfiddle for this would be much appreciated !

Comment: Try `.trigger('click')`

Comment: @Spokey .trigger("click") unfortunately gives the same output. See my update for the image

Comment: Weirdly enough I tried the code and it worked for me.  http://jsfiddle.net/d35z6t9y/ Does it skip it because `tab.attr("data-saved") == "saved"` is not true anymore?

Comment: @Spokey. Please take a look at update 2.

Comment: @Max I do bind the events after html loaded. These tabs were generated through JavaScript after the user clicked a certain element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try adding `return false;` at the end, when binding `.castor-close` click event

```
$(".castor-tabs").on("click", ".castor-close", function() {
    var tab = $(this).parent();
    if(tab.attr("data-saved") == "saved") {
        // File is saved

        if($(".castor-tab").length > 1) {
            // 1 element is 'tab' the other is a second tab
            if(tab.next().length > 0) {
                // If element is to the right
                window.newTab = tab.next();
            } else if(tab.prev().length > 0) {
                // If element is to the left
                window.newTab = tab.prev();
            }
        } else {
            window.newTab = false;
        }

        var editor = tab.attr("data-editor");
        $("#" + editor).remove(); // textarea linked to CodeMirror
        $("#" + editor + "editor").remove(); // Huge CodeMirror-element
        tab.remove();

        if(window.newTab) {
            console.log("window.newTab.click()");
            console.log(window.newTab.click()); // Simulate click()
        }
    } else {
        // File isn't saved
    }

    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of simulating a click, why not just pull the click logic out of your click function and just call the javascript function using the arguments that you'll need to perform your business logic?

Comment: You changed the line '$(".castor-tabs").on("click", ".castor-close", function() {' to '$(".castor-tabs").on("click",function() {' This is not what I want since the event is for the ".castor-close" element. These elements are dynamically generated.

Comment: I made an edit that shows castor-close as a red box element, and clicking it works with the above code.

Comment: I already knew the click event on .castor-close worked. But I want to click the next tab on the end of the code. This doesn't work

Comment: Still works after I add the other code. Not sure what the issue is.

Comment: Okay I completely misunderstood what was happening here. See my last edit please. There's no code, it's more of a conceptual advisement.

Comment: You do have a point there. Eventhough still needed this answer for that to work that would be cleaner code. I will change that. +1 for the effort and this advice.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working but not able to trigger click event binded to `castor-close` because `i` tag is empty. Put some text in it and check

```
<span class="castor-close"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-times">Click me</i></span>
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/j44qzg6z/1/)**

Comment: The "castor-close" element does get triggered. The <i></i> element must be empty because it is an icon from Font Awesome http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/

Comment: Then in that case your code should work as it is, check for console errors if any.

Answer (score 0):

Your click handler has the requirement that the click target should have the class castor-close but when you are calling click via JavaScript you are clicking the parent element instead (.castor-tab), and the click handler doesn't react.

Comment: I do try to click the parent element. See the onclick element in the second JavaScript draft in my question